# Rename individual in Protege

Tags: protege

With others types, like classes or properties it works to rename object. But for individual I can't find such option.

Is it possible to rename individual without deleting and recreating it? And if not, why?

Answer (score 3):

In order to rename an individual or any other entity on Protégé you will need to click on the entity and choose: `Refactor -> Rename Entity...`

This will open the following dialog where you can enter the new name:

[image]

Another way of doing this is clicking the entity and then pressing `Ctr + U`, this shortcut will open the same dialog (and it's way faster if you have to rename many things).

Answer (score 2):

Found a solution

Select the entity and go to the top menu - Refactor > Rename Entity and you'll get a renaming dialogue.

Answer (score 1):

Renaming a named individual is the same as renaming any other entity from OWLAPI, so if you can't find it in the UI it might just be a missing functionality.

If you wish to write Java code with the owlapi, you can use `OWLEntityRenamer`.

Editing with an XML tool will also work, for XML formats - however the operations will be different for rdf/XML and owl/XML.

Plain text editing will also work. Pay attention to name changes that also change the namespace, though - it might require changes in the declared entities.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't found any capabilities to edit from UI, but it's possible to edit from any XML-editor

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to create a slot "name" then go to the instance you created and give the name you wish.
To display the instance with the name you just gave go to the instance browser->menu->select display slot->choose name.You can see  [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qoNvJ.png) a screenshot which will make it clear!